# How to prevent RSpec from abbreviating match_array output?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have just noticed that RSpec's `match_array` is abbreviating the error response. e.g.,

```
expected collection contained: [beginning, of, the, array....end, of, the, array]
```

This did not use to be the case. Previously the output displayed the entire array contents, making it easier to identify what is causing the problem.

It has been some time since I've had a failing `match_array` in these tests, so I'm not sure what has changed. Is there a setting to provide a more verbose `match_array` message?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with arrays of integers. Please provide an example with context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best workaround for Rspec string truncation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58632823/whats-the-best-workaround-for-rspec-string-truncation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure RSpec to output full array values using the `expect_with` configuration `max_formatted_output_length`:

```
RSpec.configure do |rspec|
  rspec.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.max_formatted_output_length = nil
  end
end
```

Setting it to `nil` will prevent RSpec from truncating the formatted output! Setting it to an integer will change the maximum number of characters in the formatted output. It is 200 by default.

Documentation: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec%2FExpectations%2FConfiguration:max_formatted_output_length=