# What's the best workaround for Rspec string truncation?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm looking for a work-around for this RSpec misfeature: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2535.

An RSpec equality assertion on two long-ish strings may result in the differing parts of the strings being elided.

For example, if the expected value is:

```
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

and the actual value is:

````
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"```
````

the output may be:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(g.to_whitespace_escaped_xwiki).to eq(expect)

   expected: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        got: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
   (compared using ==)
```

The portions that differ are not output.

Comment: As noted in the github issue you reference: A quick hack could be to set `RSpec::Support::ObjectFormatter.default_instance.max_formatted_output_length = n` to a high enough value. Or you could just otherwise print the result to the console if the strings don't match.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent RSpec from abbreviating match\_array output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670959/how-to-prevent-rspec-from-abbreviating-match-array-output)

Answer (score 9):

RSpec has a setting to set the maximum character length that it will print while formatting an object:

```
RSpec.configure do |rspec|
  rspec.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.max_formatted_output_length = nil
  end
end
```

You can set length to `nil` to prevent RSpec from doing truncation.
Setting it to an integer will change the maximum number of characters in the formatted output (`200` by default).

Documentation: http://rspec.info/documentation/3.9/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Expectations/Configuration.html#max_formatted_output_length=-instance_method

Answer (score -1):

What about?

```
expected = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaA".split('')


actual = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa".split('')



p (expected.reject.with_index { |ex, ind| actual[ind] == ex }) # ["a", "A"]

p (expected.map.with_index { |ex, ind| [actual[ind], ex, ind] }).
reject { |actual_ch, expected_ch, index | actual_ch == expected_ch} #[["A", "a", 27], [nil, "A", 52]]
```